# How do we free memory of node carrying pointer to some location

Tags: c, linked-list

I have link list whose node structure is given below

```
  struct node
  {
  char *p;
  struct node *next;
  }*start;
```

Now we char *p is pointer to memory  location which allocated by malloc call.Similarly the whole is also allocated using malloc. Now would like to free the space occupied by both the malloc call ,something like this below

```
  main()
 {
   struct node *tmp;
   tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   tmp->next=NULL;
   tmp->p=malloc(2*sizeof(int));

   free(tmp->p);
   free(tmp);

 }
```

Is it the right way to free memory or something is required here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right way but don't forget to assign pointers to NULL after using free otherwise the pointers will become dangling pointers.

Use them like this -

free(tmp->p);
tmp->p = NULL;

Comment: Yes absolutly fine about the point tmp->p-NULL but just would like to know if we don't tmp->p=NULL statement will there be chances of segmentation fault?

Comment: no in this case there are no chances of segfault since u don't dereference the dangling pointers. Just the presence of dangling pointers in your code does not result in segfault. Segfault occurs when u try to use the dangling pointers due to honest mistakes. segfault can occur if u try to dereference pointer p inside the node after freeing it. Something like this will result in segfault -> free(tmp->p); *(tmp->p); // segfault.

Comment: i tried to print this statment *(tmp->p) nd still got away with segmentation fault

Comment: actually once you have freed the memory after that you should not use it otherwise it will result in undefined behaviour but it doesn't mean you cannot use it. Here whats happening is the memory is freed but it is still not allocated again so you are not getting any segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

you are freeing correctly, although normally you would have a pointer to the first node then loop through the list by following the pointers. e.g.

```
struct node *first;
... list created, first pointing to first in list, where last next is == NULL ...

while (first != NULL) 
{
  struct node* next = first->next;
  free( first->p );
  free( first );
  first = next;
}
```

btw why do you declare `p` as `char*` but allocate ints? typo?

Comment: did you see the point made by Amelioration, assign pointers to NULL after freeing it? Don't you think its quite important point he made